# iOS - UIImageView - how to handle UIImage image orientation

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, orientation

Is it possible to setup `UIImageView` to handle image orientation? When I set the `UIImageView` to image with orientation *RIGHT* (it is photo from camera roll), the image is rotated to right, but I want to show it in proper orientation, as it was taken.

I know I can rotate image data but it is possible to do it more elegant?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

If I understand, what you want to do is disregard the orientation of the UIImage? If so then you could do this:

```
UIImage *originalImage = [... whatever ...];

UIImage *imageToDisplay =
     [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[originalImage CGImage]
              scale:[originalImage scale]
              orientation: UIImageOrientationUp];
```

So you're creating a new UIImage with the same pixel data as the original (referenced via its CGImage property) but you're specifying an orientation that doesn't rotate the data.

Comment: By the way, how can I actually rotate the image data?

Comment: I guess you'd create a suitably sized `CGContext` with `CGBitmapContextCreate` (or with the `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` shorthand), use `CGContextRotateCTM` to set a rotation, use either `drawInRect:` on the `UIImage` or `CGContextDrawImage` with the image's `CGImage` property, then convert the context to an image either with `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` (and, then, `UIGraphicsEndImageContext`) if you used UIKit to create the context, or `CGBitmapContextCreateImage` if you were sticking with the Core Graphics. UIKit isn't very thread safe, but the code would be neater.

Comment: I can't get this to work when I put the image in an ImageView...it just displays the image with it's original orientation even though I'm creating the image with mirrored orientation: [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage scale:image.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUpMirrored]...the OP asked about using an ImageView but I can't get this solution to work in an ImageView...

Comment: Works for PNG, however, not for HEIC.

Answer (score 54):

You can completely avoid manually doing the transforms and scaling yourself, as suggested by an0 in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10611036/2067021):

```
- (UIImage *)normalizedImage {
    if (self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return self; 

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, self.scale);
    [self drawInRect:(CGRect){0, 0, self.size}];
    UIImage *normalizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return normalizedImage;
}
```

The documentation for the UIImage methods [size](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW21) and [drawInRect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW26) explicitly states that they take into account orientation.

Comment: This is a life saver.

Comment: where do i paste this?

Answer (score 35):

Swift 3.1

```
func fixImageOrientation(_ image: UIImage)->UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)
    image.draw(at: .zero)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage ?? image
}
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution :)

Comment: you deserve all the bits my friend

Comment: This is better than [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8915809/419348). This works in swift 4, but that doesn't.

Comment: Thanks. This one works if you need to upload your image to server, not only display as most other answers.

Comment: works great. Takes any image and saves it with .up orientation

Comment: Works for swift 5.5 as well

Comment: You are a real life hero my friend! I can't believe how long it took me to find this answer! Thank you!!

Comment: One thing that I noticed though is that these images are about 2 MB larger (the jpeg-version of the images with no compression) than the normal UIImage. Not sure why but I thought I'd at least point it out in case it was important to anyone.

Answer (score 32):

This method first checks the current orientation of UIImage and then it changes the orientation in a clockwise way and return UIImage.You can show this image as

> self.imageView.image = rotateImage(currentUIImage)

```
   func rotateImage(image:UIImage)->UIImage
    {
        var rotatedImage = UIImage();
        switch image.imageOrientation
        {
            case UIImageOrientation.Right:
            rotatedImage = UIImage(CGImage:image.CGImage!, scale: 1, orientation:UIImageOrientation.Down);
            
           case UIImageOrientation.Down:
            rotatedImage = UIImage(CGImage:image.CGImage!, scale: 1, orientation:UIImageOrientation.Left);
            
            case UIImageOrientation.Left:
            rotatedImage = UIImage(CGImage:image.CGImage!, scale: 1, orientation:UIImageOrientation.Up);
    
             default:
            rotatedImage = UIImage(CGImage:image.CGImage!, scale: 1, orientation:UIImageOrientation.Right);
        }
        return rotatedImage;
    }
```

#### Swift 4 version

```
extension UIImage {

func rotate() -> UIImage {
    var rotatedImage = UIImage()
    guard let cgImage = cgImage else {
        print("could not rotate image")
        return self
    }
    switch imageOrientation {
    case .right:
        rotatedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: scale, orientation: .down)
    case .down:
        rotatedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: scale, orientation: .left)
    case .left:
        rotatedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: scale, orientation: .up)
    default:
        rotatedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: scale, orientation: .right)
    }
    
    return rotatedImage
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Varender, and thanks for helping on SO. Could you develop a little on how you think this might help Martin? How **more elegant** than rotating data is your solution?

Comment: 1. we will take the current UIImage from the UIImageView 2.we will call this method (rotateImage) and passing this current UIImage as an argument  3. storing the returned value into  UIImageView.image   /* this will rotate the data within image view  :) :)

Comment: sir according to me it's the best answer because if we will rotate the whole UIImageView then the UIImageView  X  be a negative value . But If we rotate the data then the UIImageView will stay in place and only the data will be rotated.If you take a square UIImageView then you can simply transform the whole UIImageView using CGAffineTransformMakeRotate.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Worked like a charm :)

Comment: in swift 3 : rotatedImage = UIImage(cgImage:image.cgImage!, scale: 1, orientation:UIImageOrientation.right)

Comment: This will work for rotating your view for **display**.
But, if you need to, for example, upload your `UIImage` somewhere using Alamofire or whatever, it will not work. 
For **uploading**, use @Aqua 's answer `fixImageOrientation(_:)`

Answer (score 26):

I converted the code in [Anomie's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5427890/433373) (copy-pasted above by suvish valsan) into **Swift**:

```
func fixOrientation() -> UIImage {
    if self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.Up {
        return self
    }

    var transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

    switch self.imageOrientation {
    case .Down, .DownMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, self.size.height)
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, CGFloat(M_PI));

    case .Left, .LeftMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, CGFloat(M_PI_2));

    case .Right, .RightMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, self.size.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, CGFloat(-M_PI_2));

    case .Up, .UpMirrored:
        break
    }

    switch self.imageOrientation {

    case .UpMirrored, .DownMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0)
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1)

    case .LeftMirrored, .RightMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.height, 0)
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);

    default:
        break;
    }

    // Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
    // calculated above.
    let ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(
        nil,
        Int(self.size.width),
        Int(self.size.height),
        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(self.CGImage),
        0,
        CGImageGetColorSpace(self.CGImage),
        UInt32(CGImageGetBitmapInfo(self.CGImage).rawValue)
    )

    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);

    switch self.imageOrientation {
    case .Left, .LeftMirrored, .Right, .RightMirrored:
        // Grr...
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.height,self.size.width), self.CGImage);

    default:
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width,self.size.height), self.CGImage);
        break;
    }

    // And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
    let cgimg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx)

    let img = UIImage(CGImage: cgimg!)

    return img;
}
```

(I replaced all occurencies of the parameter `image` with `self`, because my code is an extension on `UIImage`).

---

**EDIT:** Swift 3 version.

The method returns an optional, because many of the intermediate calls can fail and I don't like to use `!`.

```
func fixOrientation() -> UIImage? {

    guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else {
        return nil
    }

    if self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.up {
        return self
    }

    let width  = self.size.width
    let height = self.size.height

    var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity

    switch self.imageOrientation {
    case .down, .downMirrored:
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: width, y: height)
        transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi)

    case .left, .leftMirrored:
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: width, y: 0)
        transform = transform.rotated(by: 0.5*CGFloat.pi)

    case .right, .rightMirrored:
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: height)
        transform = transform.rotated(by: -0.5*CGFloat.pi)

    case .up, .upMirrored:
        break
    }

    switch self.imageOrientation {
    case .upMirrored, .downMirrored:
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: width, y: 0)
        transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1)

    case .leftMirrored, .rightMirrored:
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: height, y: 0)
        transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1)

    default:
        break;
    }

    // Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
    // calculated above.
    guard let colorSpace = cgImage.colorSpace else {
        return nil
    }

    guard let context = CGContext(
        data: nil,
        width: Int(width),
        height: Int(height),
        bitsPerComponent: cgImage.bitsPerComponent,
        bytesPerRow: 0,
        space: colorSpace,
        bitmapInfo: UInt32(cgImage.bitmapInfo.rawValue)
        ) else {
            return nil
    }

    context.concatenate(transform);

    switch self.imageOrientation {

    case .left, .leftMirrored, .right, .rightMirrored:
        // Grr...
        context.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: height, height: width))

    default:
        context.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
    }

    // And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
    guard let newCGImg = context.makeImage() else {
        return nil
    }

    let img = UIImage(cgImage: newCGImg)

    return img;
}
```

(Note: Swift 3 version odes compile under Xcode 8.1, but haven't tested it actually works. There might be a typo somewhere, mixed up width/height, etc. Feel free to point/fix any errors).

Comment: I have used above code after converting to swift 3.Check my answer below if anybody needs swift 3 version

Comment: Image orientation not changed at all. Sorry, i am new to iOS development. What i did are, i use the function to UIImage extension, then set it programmatically inside `func viewDidLoad`. This image is from samsung phone https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipN4DE_xAT-RyGYM3zPxiJyj5gPNgQiDHyp1M2JSD4CZSky43evQTjPKnMsiq4E_6g?key=YV92QnVaY1pyTTEybVFvbmdIS3R5c3A0ajJqaVJn and has 270 CW orientation exif data. Here how i use it `let background: UIImage? = UIImage(named: "background_image")?.fixOrientation()
        backgroundImage.image = background`

Comment: Anyone getting memory leak issues using this @Nicolas?  looks like the CGImages are not being deallocated.  My app is a mass photo management app and deals with many photos.  This function appears to be leaking memory every time it is run.  Are there any quick fixes for this?

Comment: @MichaelReilly Hmm, havnen't looked at it in detail, but the CoreGraphics calls should work with ARC in swift.

Comment: @MichaelReilly I found this answer, which seems to corroborate my observation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25790214/433373

Comment: @MichaelReilly Could you share more details of your memory leaks? I havent used this function myself in a while, and I no longer have access to the actual project in which I used this code.

Answer (score 10):

UIImage extension in Swift. You don't need to do all that flipping at all, really. Objective-C [original is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10611036/8047), but I've added the bit that respects the alpha of the original image (crudely, but it works to differentiate opaque images from transparent images).

```
// from https://github.com/mbcharbonneau/UIImage-Categories/blob/master/UIImage%2BAlpha.m
// Returns true if the image has an alpha layer
    private func hasAlpha() -> Bool {
        guard let cg = self.cgImage else { return false }
        let alpha = cg.alphaInfo
        let retVal = (alpha == .first || alpha == .last || alpha == .premultipliedFirst || alpha == .premultipliedLast)
        return retVal
    }

    func normalizedImage() -> UIImage? {
        if self.imageOrientation == .up {
            return self
        }
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, !self.hasAlpha(), self.scale)
        var rect = CGRect.zero
        rect.size = self.size
        self.draw(in: rect)
        let retVal = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return retVal
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

here is a workable sample cod, considering the image orientation:

```
#define rad(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)
- (CGAffineTransform)orientationTransformedRectOfImage:(UIImage *)img
{
    CGAffineTransform rectTransform;
    switch (img.imageOrientation)
    {
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
            rectTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rad(90)), 0, -img.size.height);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
            rectTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rad(-90)), -img.size.width, 0);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
            rectTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rad(-180)), -img.size.width, -img.size.height);
            break;
        default:
            rectTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    };

    return CGAffineTransformScale(rectTransform, img.scale, img.scale);
}


- (UIImage *)croppedImage:(UIImage*)orignialImage InRect:(CGRect)visibleRect{
    //transform visible rect to image orientation
    CGAffineTransform rectTransform = [self orientationTransformedRectOfImage:orignialImage];
    visibleRect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(visibleRect, rectTransform);

    //crop image
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([orignialImage CGImage], visibleRect);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:orignialImage.scale orientation:orignialImage.imageOrientation];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I converted the code from @Nicolas Miari answer to Swift 3 in case anybody needs it

```
func fixOrientation() -> UIImage
{

    if self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.up {
        return self
    }

    var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity

    switch self.imageOrientation {
    case .down, .downMirrored:
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: self.size.width, y: self.size.height)
        transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(M_PI));

    case .left, .leftMirrored:
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: self.size.width, y: 0);
        transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(M_PI_2));

    case .right, .rightMirrored:
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: self.size.height);
        transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(-M_PI_2));

    case .up, .upMirrored:
        break
    }


    switch self.imageOrientation {

    case .upMirrored, .downMirrored:
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: self.size.width, y: 0)
        transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1)

    case .leftMirrored, .rightMirrored:
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: self.size.height, y: 0)
        transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1);

    default:
        break;
    }

    // Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
    // calculated above.
    let ctx = CGContext(
        data: nil,
        width: Int(self.size.width),
        height: Int(self.size.height),
        bitsPerComponent: self.cgImage!.bitsPerComponent,
        bytesPerRow: 0,
        space: self.cgImage!.colorSpace!,
        bitmapInfo: UInt32(self.cgImage!.bitmapInfo.rawValue)
    )



    ctx!.concatenate(transform);

    switch self.imageOrientation {

    case .left, .leftMirrored, .right, .rightMirrored:
        // Grr...
        ctx?.draw(self.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x:0 ,y: 0 ,width: self.size.height ,height:self.size.width))

    default:
        ctx?.draw(self.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x:0 ,y: 0 ,width: self.size.width ,height:self.size.height))
        break;
    }

    // And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
    let cgimg = ctx!.makeImage()

    let img = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg!)

    return img;

}
```

Comment: After capture the image in Delegate methods
`imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]
        let imageCaptured:UIImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage`

image is always rightOrientation and this method is returning  back image  :(

Comment: Yes image orientation is alway .right but It displays correctly on UIImageView. Apple has some internal data which is used here to display corrrectly

Answer (score 5):

If you need to rotate and fix the image orientation below extension would be useful.

```
extension UIImage {

    public func imageRotatedByDegrees(degrees: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        //Calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space
        let rotatedViewBox: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height))
        let t: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: degrees * CGFloat.pi / 180)
        rotatedViewBox.transform = t
        let rotatedSize: CGSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size
        //Create the bitmap context
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize)
        let bitmap: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        //Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
        bitmap.translateBy(x: rotatedSize.width / 2, y: rotatedSize.height / 2)
        //Rotate the image context
        bitmap.rotate(by: (degrees * CGFloat.pi / 180))
        //Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
        bitmap.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        bitmap.draw(self.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: -self.size.width / 2, y: -self.size.height / 2, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height))
        let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage
    }


    public func fixedOrientation() -> UIImage {
        if imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.up {
            return self
        }

        var transform: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity

        switch imageOrientation {
        case UIImageOrientation.down, UIImageOrientation.downMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: size.width, y: size.height)
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi)
            break
        case UIImageOrientation.left, UIImageOrientation.leftMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: size.width, y: 0)
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi/2)
            break
        case UIImageOrientation.right, UIImageOrientation.rightMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: size.height)
            transform = transform.rotated(by: -CGFloat.pi/2)
            break
        case UIImageOrientation.up, UIImageOrientation.upMirrored:
            break
        }

        switch imageOrientation {
        case UIImageOrientation.upMirrored, UIImageOrientation.downMirrored:
            transform.translatedBy(x: size.width, y: 0)
            transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1)
            break
        case UIImageOrientation.leftMirrored, UIImageOrientation.rightMirrored:
            transform.translatedBy(x: size.height, y: 0)
            transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1)
        case UIImageOrientation.up, UIImageOrientation.down, UIImageOrientation.left, UIImageOrientation.right:
            break
        }

        let ctx: CGContext = CGContext(data: nil,
                                       width: Int(size.width),
                                       height: Int(size.height),
                                       bitsPerComponent: self.cgImage!.bitsPerComponent,
                                       bytesPerRow: 0,
                                       space: self.cgImage!.colorSpace!,
                                       bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)!

        ctx.concatenate(transform)

        switch imageOrientation {
        case UIImageOrientation.left, UIImageOrientation.leftMirrored, UIImageOrientation.right, UIImageOrientation.rightMirrored:
            ctx.draw(self.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.height, height: size.width))
        default:
            ctx.draw(self.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
            break
        }

        let cgImage: CGImage = ctx.makeImage()!

        return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Waseem05 for his Swift 3 translation but his method only worked for me when I wrapped it inside an extension to UIImage and placed it outside/below the parent class like so:

```
extension UIImage {

        func fixOrientation() -> UIImage
        {

            if self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.up {
            return self
        }

        var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity

        switch self.imageOrientation {
        case .down, .downMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: self.size.width, y: self.size.height)
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(M_PI));

        case .left, .leftMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: self.size.width, y: 0);
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(M_PI_2));

        case .right, .rightMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: self.size.height);
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(-M_PI_2));

        case .up, .upMirrored:
            break
        }


        switch self.imageOrientation {

        case .upMirrored, .downMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: self.size.width, y: 0)
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1)

        case .leftMirrored, .rightMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: self.size.height, y: 0)
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1);

        default:
            break;
        }

        // Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
        // calculated above.
        let ctx = CGContext(
            data: nil,
            width: Int(self.size.width),
            height: Int(self.size.height),
            bitsPerComponent: self.cgImage!.bitsPerComponent,
            bytesPerRow: 0,
            space: self.cgImage!.colorSpace!,
            bitmapInfo: UInt32(self.cgImage!.bitmapInfo.rawValue)
        )



        ctx!.concatenate(transform);

        switch self.imageOrientation {

        case .left, .leftMirrored, .right, .rightMirrored:
            // Grr...
            ctx?.draw(self.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x:0 ,y: 0 ,width: self.size.height ,height:self.size.width))

        default:
            ctx?.draw(self.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x:0 ,y: 0 ,width: self.size.width ,height:self.size.height))
            break;
        }

        // And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
        let cgimg = ctx!.makeImage()

        let img = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg!)

        return img;

    }
}
```

Then called it with:

```
let correctedImage:UIImage = wonkyImage.fixOrientation()
```

And all was then well!  Apple should make it easier to discard orientation when we don't need front/back camera and up/down/left/right device orientation metadata.

Answer (score 3):

```
extension UIImage {
    func fixImageOrientation() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size)
        self.draw(at: .zero)
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage ?? self
    }
}
```

1. Create extension like top example.
2. Call it: `imageView.image?.fixImageOrientation()` or `UIImage(named: "someImage").fixImageOrientation()`
3. Good luck all!

Comment: This works fine. But the memory is building up like anything and the app is crashing if this is called in loops.

Comment: @abhimuralidharan, I didn't check in loop it, but 100% exists a way to apply.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3.0 version of Tommy's answer

```
let imageToDisplay = UIImage.init(cgImage: originalImage.cgImage!, scale: originalImage.scale, orientation: UIImageOrientation.up)
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired from @Aqua Answer.....

**in Objective C**

```
- (UIImage *)fixImageOrientation:(UIImage *)img {

   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img.size);
   [img drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

   UIImage *newImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   if (newImg) {
       return newImg;
   }

   return img;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried the checkmarked solution and it doesn't work for me.
But the below solution works for fixing orientation from camera before converting to png.

**Swift 5:**

```
let imageToDisplay = originalImage.resize(new: originalImage.resize)
```

Comment: Try to answer with more descriptive comment and to answer the question with a suitable answer