# Why does this code resizing an image rotate it 90 degrees from original?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have an iPad app where I'm using the camera.  The original image is 480 x 640.  I am attempting to resize it to 124 x 160 and then store it in CoreData using this code that I found on the internet:

```
- (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image newSize:(CGSize)newSize {

CGRect newRect = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height));
CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Set the quality level to use when rescaling
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, newSize.height);

CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical);

// Draw into the context; this scales the image
CGContextDrawImage(context, newRect, imageRef);

// Get the resized image from the context and a UIImage
CGImageRef newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];

CGImageRelease(newImageRef);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;
```

}

The image is returned to me rotated counter-clockwise 90 degrees and I don't see why.  I have tried commenting out this statement:

```
CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, newSize.height);
```

but it makes no difference.  What is wrong here?

Comment: Isn't the rotation of an image a property of the meta data and not an actual realignment of the pixels?  At least that's how I think it works with pictures captured with the iPod/iPhone/iPad's cameras (as well as many other consumer cameras)

Comment: He who lives by the copy-and-pasted code snippet dies by the copy-and-pasted code snippet. The thing to do here is think. UIImage has orientation information. CGImage does not. Hence you are throwing that information away and never restoring it.

Comment: OK... I've tried everything suggested here, and nothing helps...  I understand what matt is saying, but that doesn't help... all I wanted to do was save space by scaling the image... seems like this is a lot of work for little payoff...

Comment: Is the orientation of the UIImage set, and if so what is it set to?

Comment: no, it's the raw UIImage taken with the iPad camera in portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody who made suggestions.. I kept looking and found this, which scales and keeps the orientation:

```
    CGRect screenRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120.0, 160.0);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size);
    [image drawInRect:screenRect blendMode:kCGBlendModePlusDarker alpha:1];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to consider the orientation of the image when drawing it like this. Check this answer [iOS - UIImageView - how to handle UIImage image orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915630/ios-uiimageview-how-to-handle-uiimage-image-orientation)