# CGImageCreateWithImageInRect not working properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage

I am trying to use CGImageCreateWithImageInRect to get a sub-image from an image but it's not working properly. It returns the image from a random place in the image, rather than the one I specify. Please take a look at the following image;

[image]

My code is:

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], CGRectMake(524, 1331, 600, 600));
UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

But that doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: In addition to @HalR's answer, note that the y axis is flipped in Core Graphics by default, so you probably want y = 0 here.

Comment: Upvote for cleveland :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is likely that your image has a UIImageOrientation set for it that is different from what you are expecting.  The iOS will display the image properly, yet the image will be stored sideways (for lack of a better term).

So when you say give me the rect starting at x, y you will get y, x instead, or some random craziness because you are accessing a rect that is outside of the normal range.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15039609/793607) talks about fixing the orientation.

Answer (score 2):

please see followed answer, you need transform the rect or transform the image. I prefer to transforming the rect.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21560825/2482283