# iOS JPEG images rotated 90 degrees

Tags: ios, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using picker view to select image from photo album. I use above code:

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

updateImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

[self.view addSubview:[MUtility sharedObject].loadingView ];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

After that i upload to server and i use this code

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(updateImage, 0.1);
```

But this image rotated 90 degrees. Only portrait photo rotated. 
How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Refer this answer, it will solve your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427656/ios-uiimagepickercontroller-result-image-orientation-after-upload

Comment: There another solution to this problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204495/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-image-orientation) along with a lengthy explanation of what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

`UIImage` has a `imageOrientation` property which can be used to check and resolve the issue.Find this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915630/ios-uiimageview-how-to-handle-uiimage-image-orientation).