# CGImageRelease in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cgimage

In Objc I use `CGImageRelease` method after the treatment of an image. But in Swift this method is not available.

On the Apple documentation after `Retaining and Releasing Images` there is a `2 Objective-C symbols hidden`

My question is, why is there no more `CGImageRelease` in Swift ? And have we to call another method to replace it ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`CGImage` is now managed by ARC. `CGImageRelease()` is no longer required on it. You can know this by looking in CGImage.h and noting that it includes the macro `CF_IMPLICIT_BRIDGING_ENABLED`. This indicates that Apple has audited this file to make sure it conforms to memory-management naming conventions so ARC can memory manage objects returned from functions in this file.

---

EDIT: I was reading over this and realized I was misleading. I don't mean to say that `CGImageRelease` isn't needed in ObjC (which is pretty much what I implied here…) I just mean that because of the auditing, Swift is able to handle it. In ObjC code, you still need to release these objects.

Comment: I doubt it. ARC introduces a number of restrictions that are pretty easy to avoid in ObjC, but extremely common in C. You can't put an ARC-managed element in a `struct` for instance. It is tricky to pass an ARC-managed element as a `void*`. Apple's focus is on Swift, and I doubt they would spend a lot of time enhancing C. They would tend, IMO, to spend that time improving Swift as a replacement for whatever you were doing in C.

Comment: If _CGImageRelease_ is not needed anymore why memory usage is increasing everytime we use _context.createCGImage_

Comment: @the It depends on the specifics of your case. Open a question that with code that reproduces your symptom and a description of exactly what you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no more CGImageRelease in Swift, and there is no another method to replace it.

> - Swift uses ARC exclusively, so there’s no room for a call to CFRelease or __bridge_retained.
> - For types returned from C functions, we can call takeRetainedValue() / takeUnretainedValue() to get a Swift-managed value.
> - With the macro CF_IMPLICIT_BRIDGING_ENABLED, that turn on the Clang arc_cf_code_audited, Swift can handle the memory management for return value

For detail: https://nshipster.com/unmanaged/