# compress Size of Image without convert to NSData

Tags: ios, uiimage, uicollectionview, compression, afnetworking

I have a UICollectionView, in which I am showing some images by downloading it from server. To show these Images I an using AFNetworking class method  **setImageWithURL:(URL*)**.

Image size is about (968, 968) this is taking hell lot of memory. If I convert these Images to NSData and compressed it by UIImageJPEGRepresentation method it is taking a lot of time to convert Image into NSData. Is there any way to reduce size of images and show into collection view cell without much delay.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIImage *)scaleAndRotateImage:(UIImage *) image {

 //Resolution you want
int kMaxResolution = 1024;

CGImageRef imgRef = image.CGImage;

CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);


CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
if (width > kMaxResolution || height > kMaxResolution) {
    CGFloat ratio = width/height;
    if (ratio > 1) {
        bounds.size.width = kMaxResolution;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width / ratio;
    }
    else {
        bounds.size.height = kMaxResolution;
        bounds.size.width = bounds.size.height * ratio;
    }
}

CGFloat scaleRatio = bounds.size.width / width;
CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(imgRef), CGImageGetHeight(imgRef));
CGFloat boundHeight;
UIImageOrientation orient = image.imageOrientation;
switch(orient) {

    case UIImageOrientationUp: //EXIF = 1
        transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored: //EXIF = 2
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, 0.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationDown: //EXIF = 3
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored: //EXIF = 4
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored: //EXIF = 5
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, imageSize.width);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeft: //EXIF = 6
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.width);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored: //EXIF = 7
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationRight: //EXIF = 8
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, 0.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
        break;

    default:
        [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"Invalid image orientation"];

}

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

if (orient == UIImageOrientationRight || orient == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, -scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -height, 0);
}
else {
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleRatio, -scaleRatio);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -height);
}

CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);

CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imgRef);
UIImage *imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return imageCopy;
```

}

Comment: This failed for me with orientation EXIF = 5... but this solution here worked great: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24770069/2057171

Then I could manually scale later

Comment: Great!, Thanks @AlbertRenshaw for the updated source, I appreciate.