# Why a picture animation works different when image is oriented differently

Tags: ios, swift

I'm facing a big issue.. And I just don't know why it does not work correctly.
I'm making a gallery application and want to have smooth transition between gallery and fullscreen image.

I though my animation worked perfectly.. but I captured a picture with different orientation and my animation doesn't work anymore.
Do you have any idea why my animation is dependent to the orientation of the picture ?

here is my working animation.

[image]

Here is my broken animation

[image]

As you can see the height and the width are the same, and this is not a ratio problem.

here is my animation

```
    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

    guard   let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to),
            let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from)?.childViewControllers.first as? NavigationGalleryViewController,
            let fromView = fromVC.collectionView?.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? InstallationViewCell
        else {
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
            return
    }

    let finalFrame = toView.frame

    let viewToAnimate = UIImageView(frame: originFrame)
    viewToAnimate.image = fromView.imageView.image
    viewToAnimate.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    viewToAnimate.clipsToBounds = true
    fromView.imageView.isHidden = true

    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
    containerView.addSubview(toView)
    containerView.addSubview(viewToAnimate)

    toView.isHidden = true

    // Determine the final image height based on final frame width and image aspect ratio
    let imageAspectRatio = viewToAnimate.image!.size.width / viewToAnimate.image!.size.height
    var finalImageheight = finalFrame.width / imageAspectRatio

    if (finalImageheight > UIScreen.main.bounds.height) {
        finalImageheight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    }

    // Animate size and position
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
        viewToAnimate.frame.size.width = finalFrame.width
        viewToAnimate.frame.size.height = finalImageheight
        viewToAnimate.center = CGPoint(x: finalFrame.midX, y: finalFrame.midY)
    }, completion:{ _ in
        toView.isHidden = false
        fromView.imageView.isHidden = false
        viewToAnimate.removeFromSuperview()
        transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
    })

}
```

All my frames are good in either of way, I checked them 4 times, my begin and ending frames are good.

[image: Frames]

Is there something I should know about pictures, orientation or animation ?

Comment: Did you check to see if the viewToAnimate.frame is not a relative frame to the collection cell itself? because then having an X of 214 makes it go out of bounds. What are the parameters of the frame for the working animation and what is the value of "originFrame"?

Comment: Try setting `viewToAnimate.frame = fromView.superview!.convert(fromView.frame, to: transitionContext.containerView)`

Comment: How do you set `originFrame` in this statement `let viewToAnimate = UIImageView(frame: originFrame)`?

Comment: see this http://blog.jtribe.com.au/title/

Answer (score 2):

UIImage orientations is one big messy bug. The easiest way is to normalize all UIImage instances in imageViews to one orientation. How it's done if well described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37292818/1264313)

Comment: Actually, change the orientation does fix my problem, but it's not a fix, it's a bypass.. 

But at least I know that the problem comes from the orientation