# Image displayed upside down in mac preview, but displayed right side up in the browser

Tags: image, uiimage, jpeg

A jpg is rendered upside down on my mac but correctly in a safari browser on the same mac.  What is the orientation data that is not correctly being read?  Is it in the EXIF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to display it with the correct orientation

```
  if (image.imageOrientation != UIImageOrientationUp)
  {            
    image = [UIImage 
              imageWithCGImage: image.CGImage 
              scale: 1 
              orientation: UIImageOrientationUp];
  }
```

based on an answer by ravin [Save UIImage, Load it in Wrong Orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838699/save-uiimage-load-it-in-wrong-orientation)