# iOS UIImage taken in portrait_upside_down has a wrong imageOrientation value

Tags: ios, uiimage, orientation, uiimageorientation

The photos, taken in portrait upside-down mode with iOS device, and after that copied to Xcode project.

```
let testImage = UIImage(named: "4.JPG")
print(testImage!.imageOrientation.rawValue)
```

UIImageOrientation value always results 0 (.up orientation), though it should be .left.

And I've rechecked the images with EXIF viewers - it should be .left. Any ideas why could this happen?

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319861/image-displayed-upside-down-in-mac-preview-but-displayed-right-side-up-in-the-b/11323469#11323469)